# coded ui -- are test results stored for assert methods in html

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to store the test results for my assert method in a excel.

But I checked the html file created in "TestResults" folder of the project, it does not records anything about the assert method.

[The html log file is shown as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B0mT.png)

How do I see the test result for each assertion method created in this TestMethod

Comment: You cannot. There are numerous questions on the web about the same topic, there are also some ideas on how to achieve what you want. Try searching the web.

Comment: do you happen to know any site or blog. Because I have been searching this for weeks and couldn't find anything yet

Comment: Try a web search for "coded ui continue after assert failure" and similar. Also [look here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/629618ff-3e3c-4478-90f7-ac7e25b341b4/ability-to-viewreport-assertions-within-coded-ui-test-without-visual-studio-2010?forum=vstest).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the link was very helpful. Meanwhile I found another method to get my assert results. It goes as follows :-
(1) Add your assert method to UIMap.cs 
(2) apply a try catch for each Asser.AreEqual(expected, actual)
(3) Now while executing if you land in the catch block, record appropriate message

Like this...

```
public void AssertMethod_Panel()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            HtmlDiv uISolutPane = this.UIInternetExploWindow.UIDocument1.UISolutPane;
            #endregion



            try
            {
                // Verify that the 'Exists' property of panel equals 'True'
                Assert.AreEqual(this.AssertMethod_Panel.uISolutPaneExists, uISolutPane.Exists);

            }
            catch
            {

                File.AppendAllText("C:\\TestResultFailed.txt", "control doe not exists" + Environment.NewLine);

            }

         }
```

So if you get any entries in the "TestResultFailed.txt" that means your test has failed.

Comment: Obviously this involves a lot of work of adding my assert methods to UIMap, then writing try catch for each and every assert method.... Hope to get a more easy solution.